# Remover elemento/função Corona SDK

Tags: lua

tenho arquivo `form.lua` com o código:

```
local _M = {}

function _M.calc( a )

    local quad = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
end
return _M
```

e o arquivo `scene2.lua` com o código:

```
local form = require "form"

form.calc( )
```

Eu preciso que o `quad / function` seja removido da tela, quando for para outra cena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o composer, coloca o objeto que você quer deletar dentro de um grupo de exibição e na função hide do composer você põe o objeto para ser removido (display.remove(objeto)). Assim toda vez que esta cena que contêm o quad, vai ser removida quando for "escondida" para que outra cena apareça.